# Erro Loop Java Classe Scanner

Tags: java, loop, scanner

Quando utilizo o método nextLine() no lugar de next() no código abaixo, pula-se as interações do código e alguns campos ficam em branco.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class turma {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        final byte tamanho=10;
        byte k=tamanho;
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        float notas[][]=new float[tamanho][3];// A matriz possui 10 linhas e três colunas(uma para cada prova e a última para a média);
        String nomes[][]=new String[tamanho][2];//A matriz possui 10 linhas (alunos) e duas colunas, uma para o nome e a outra para a situação
        System.out.println("Cadastro de Turma:");
        for (byte i=0; i<=(k-1); i++) { //laço para as linhas
                System.out.println("Entre com o nome do "+(i+1)+"º aluno:");
                //entrada.nextLine();
                nomes[i][0]=entrada.nextLine();

                for (byte y=0;y<=1;y++){
                    System.out.println("Entre com a "+(y+1)+"ª nota:");
                    notas[i][y]=entrada.nextFloat();
                }//fim do for interno
                notas[i][2]=(notas[i][0]+notas[i][1])/2;
                if (notas[i][2]>=7) nomes[i][1]="Aprovado"; else nomes[i][1]="Repovado";
        }//for externo
        System.out.println("Relatório de Notas");
        System.out.println("\nNome \t\tNota 1 \t\tNota 2 \t\tMédia \t\tSituação");
        for (byte i=0; i<=(k-1);i++) System.out.println(nomes[i][0]+"\t\t"+notas[i][0]+"\t\t"+notas[i][1]+"\t\t"+notas[i][2]+"\t\t"+nomes[i][1]);

    }//fim do main
}//fim da classe
```

Comment: Essa é boa :D. Estou aqui a tentar ver o que se passa e de facto, quando chega a altura de ler o segundo ou n-ésimo nome (n != 1) ele considera vazio. Eu dei uma olhada na implementação do `nextFloat()` e observei que ele lê o próximo elemento do `buffer` (variavel `typeCache`) e converte para `float` e depois retorna (caso seja um valor inválido ele dá uma exceção, e te recomendo atentar para isso). Minha desconfiança é que ele lê somente o valor em questão, neste caso o `float` digigtado e o converte(fazendo um cast) ignorando o "\n" que neste caso é colocado em `buffer` também pelo `Enter`

Comment: Uma solução poderia colocar um `nextLine()` pra ler o suposto "\n" que não é considerado pelo `nextFloat()` após o término do ciclo interno. É apenas uma desconfiança, por isso não coloquei como resposta. Ainda estou analisando...

Comment: Também deve ter em atenção limpar o buffer de entrada. O buffer de entrada é basicamente aquilo que o utilizador escreve, se existir lá algum lixo o codigo entende que foi o utilizador e nunca vai parar para que o utilizador escreva.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1º Modo:**

```
nomes[i][0]=lerString();
for (int y=0;y<=1;y++){
     System.out.println("Entre com a "+(y+1)+"ª nota:");
     notas[i][y]=entrada.nextFloat();
}//fim do for interno

//[...]

public static String lerString(){
     return entrada.next()+entrada.nextLine();
}
```

Não esqueça de declarar o scanner `entrada` como `static` para ser reconhecido na função.

**2º Modo(recomendado)**

```
   nomes[i][0]=entrada.nextLine();
    for (int y=0;y<=1;y++){
         System.out.println("Entre com a "+(y+1)+"ª nota:");
         notas[i][y]=entrada.nextFloat();
    }//fim do for interno
    entrada.nextLine()//descarrega o buffer do teclado, antes de ler a próxima string
```

sempre que for ler uma string depois de ler um valor numérico você precisa descarregar o buffer do teclado antes de ler a string,.

Answer (score 0):

O certo seria você usar um Scanner diferente para cada tipo primitivo da variavel.
Ou limpar o conteudo dentro de seu Scanner e utiliza-lo novamente (não recomendo)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai uma gambi para resolver seu problema.

Troque isso:

```java
nomes[i][0]=entrada.nextLine();
```

Por isso:

```java
String lido = null;
do {
    lido = entrada.nextLine();
} while (lido == null || lido.trim().isEmpty());
nomes[i][0]=lido;
```

Answer (score -4):

Coloque o `Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);` depois do laço que funciona.