# Como "corrigir" uma exceção?

Tags: java

Podemos tratar uma exceção lançada por uma linha de código a fim de não deixar o programa quebrar, mas como podemos corrigi-la?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

try {
    String[] vect = new String[1];
    vect[0] = "Maria";

    int posicao = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(vect[posicao]);
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Posição inacessível !");
}
```

Se for digitado qualquer valor na variável `posicao` diferente de `0` irá lançar a exceção do `catch`, mas como podemos dar a opção de digitar novamente essa variável?

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de tentar "corrigir" a exceção depois que ela acontece, você poderia simplesmente evitar que ela aconteça.

No caso, bastaria testar a posição, verificando se o valor é válido ou não. E se não for, você pede que este seja novamente digitado, até que seja válido. Para isso podemos usar um `while (true)`:

```
int posicao;
System.out.println("Digite o valor da posição:");
while (true) {
    posicao = sc.nextInt();
    if (posicao >= 0 && posicao < vect.length) {
        break; // valor da posição válido, pode sair do while
    } else {
        System.out.println("Valor inválido, digite outro valor:");
    }
}

System.out.println(vect[posicao]);
```

O `while(true)` é uma forma de fazer um *loop* infinito. Em seguida, o valor de `posicao` é lido, e se ele for maior ou igual a zero **e** menor que o tamanho do array (`vect.length`) - ou seja, ele tem um valor que não lançará `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - eu uso o `break`, para sair do `while`.

Se o valor for inválido (negativo ou maior que o tamanho do array - ou seja, qualquer valor que lance `IndexOutOfBoundsException`), o `while` continua rodando, e outro valor é pedido, até que seja digitado um valor válido.

---

Como o `if` já garantiu que o valor de `posicao` é válido, você pode inclusive retirar o `try`/`catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException)`.

No entanto, se quiser incrementar o código, pode capturar [`java.util.InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), que é a exceção lançada por [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) caso seja digitado algo que não seja um número inteiro:

```
int posicao;
System.out.println("Digite o valor da posição:");
while (true) {
    try {
        posicao = sc.nextInt();
        if (posicao >= 0 && posicao < vect.length) {
            break; // valor da posição válido, pode sair do while
        } else {
            System.out.println("Valor inválido, digite outro valor:");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        sc.nextLine(); // limpar o buffer
        System.out.println("Valor digitado não é um número inteiro, digite outro valor:");
    }
}

System.out.println(vect[posicao]);
```

Dentro do `try` eu continuo fazendo as mesmas verificações no valor de `posicao`. Caso seja digitado algo que não seja um número inteiro (como `abc xyz` ou até mesmo `1.234`), o método `nextInt()` lança um `InputMismatchException`.

Dentro do `catch` eu chamo `nextLine()` para ["limpar" o *buffer* do `Scanner`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83443/112052), e em seguida informo ao usuário o que ocorreu e peço que ele digite novamente o valor (e o `while` continua rodando, até que seja digitado um valor válido).

---

Você está tentado [usar a exceção para controlar o fluxo do programa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48410/112052), mas neste caso não é necessário. É possível fazer as verificações e lógicas necessárias sem precisar disso, usando apenas as estruturas básicas da linguagem (`if`, `while`, etc).

*Exceto, é claro, no caso de `InputMismatchException`, já que esta exceção é o modo que o método `nextInt()` tem para indicar que não conseguiu ler um número inteiro. Mas no caso do `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, não precisa do `try`/`catch` para fazer o que você precisa.*

Comment: Sim, concordo plenamente que o uso indiscriminado de exceções é péssimo... Inclusive sou da mesma opinião, programar para que gere o menos de exception possível, sendo que muitas como  java.lang.ArithmeticException pode ser solucionada com apenas um " if ". O que eu quis saber (desculpe por não ser específico) é como "consertar" uma exceção que foi lançada excepcionalmente, usei o exemplo acima para ilustrar, fingir que esse seja um caso excepcional... Só podemos "sinalizar"  a exceção para que não quebre o programa e não realmente "tratar" de forma simples e fácil ?

Comment: @KevinRicci Depende do tipo de erro e do que vc precisa/pretende fazer. No seu exemplo, a exceção pôde ser evitada verificando o valor de `posicao`. No meu exemplo com `InputMismatchException`, a exceção é o único jeito de saber que `nextInt` falhou, e a "solução" foi pedir que digite outro número (mas poderia ser também sair do programa, ou qq outra ação que vc quisesse). Cada caso é um caso. Talvez [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/112052) te ajude - inclusive, na primeira resposta têm vários outros links interessantes

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, mas no seu caso do seu exemplo você está usando outros controladores de fluxo para controlar um controlador de fluxo(try/catch), a questão que eu quero chegar é: por si só o tratamento de exceções não possui nenhuma recursividade de realmente tratar o problema ? Ele serve apenas para falar pro programa "hey amigão, pode ser que dê uma exceção aqui, tô deixando avisado pra você não quebrar beleza ?" mas simplesmente não resolve o possível erro de forma funcional caso ocorra ?

Comment: Ele permite que o programa continue, certo, mas e se o programa necessita daquela informação que ocorreu o erro e ela simplesmente não existe pois lançou uma exceção, o programa lançaria uma série de exceções em cadeia logo em seguida ?

Comment: @KevinRicci A exceção só indica que algo errado aconteceu, mas o que fazer se ela ocorrer depende de cada caso. Por ex, se tem outro jeito de obter a informação que precisa, faça-o. Se não tem, uma decisão deve ser tomada: eu consigo prosseguir com o programa sem essa informação? Se não consigo, informo isso e/ou encerro o programa. A exceção só indica o que aconteceu, mas a decisão do que fazer com ela é do programador, e - novamente - cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Usando seu exemplo, se o programa precisa de uma informação mas ela não existe pq ocorreu um erro. A exceção por si só não tem como saber que aquela informação é necessária - isso é uma questão da lógica do programa, que só o programador conhece, por isso só ele sabe que ação tomar qdo a exceção ocorre. Tem outro jeito de obter essa informação? Posso usar algum outro valor? Tem como seguir sem a informação? Não tem jeito e o melhor é encerrar o programa (ou pedir para o usuário "tente novamente")? Essa decisão é de quem programa, a exceção por si só não tem como decidir isso

Comment: Bom, creio que minha pergunta foi sanada, e isso reforça a ideia de que exceções não devem ser usadas sem circunspeção, ela é custosa pelo que estou vendo e, ademais,  podem afetar a performance

Answer (score 3):

Para resolver seu problema basta usar um Loop infinito e permitir sua parada com o `Return` só quando as ações que você desejar acontecerem, caso houver uma exceção ele vai dar um `Continue` e voltar ao inicio do loop

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Digite a posição");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        String[] vect = new String[1];
        vect[0] = "Maria";

        int posicao = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(vect[posicao]);
        return;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Posição inacessível !");
        continue;
    }
}
```